# Java crop image?

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to get one section from an image.

**From an initial image, how can I return the section 1 below as an image itself?**

Instead of the entire 4 squares.

[image]

So in short, I wan't to get a 64 x 64 pixel sized rectangle from a base image.

How should I go about this?

Comment: so you want to crop a image?

Comment: that is a better word to use..yes, crop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
BufferedImage img= ImageIO.read(new File("image.png"));

final int w= 10;
final int h= 10;
final int rows = 5;
final int cols = 5;
BufferedImage[] tile= new BufferedImage[rows * cols];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        tile[(i * cols) + j] = img.getSubimage(
            j * w,
            i * h,
            w,
            h
        );
    }
}
```

You may check the [getSubimage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: what is an advantage to using this over below answer?

Comment: @ThatGuy343:- That is the same but I just tried to give you the complete code with logic which you might try to implement. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
BufferedImage tile = mImage.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
```

where x and y are your starting co-ordinates and w : width and h : height of sub-image.
So to get the 1st square your values will be x=0,y=0,w=64,h=64